# “Volume” vs. “issue” for a new journal

Tags: journals, terminology

Our school is publishing an academic journal soon. It will be printed annually.  How do we label it – should we use the term *volume* or *issue?*  What is the difference?

Comment: Aren't there enough journals in your field already?

Comment: As a side note: Before you go through the trouble of actually printing a journal, you should ask yourself whether anybody cares about printed journals in your field anymore.

Comment: @CapeCode Wrzlprmft What's with the rush to judgement? The pros and cons of starting a new journal are not part of the question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'm guessing it's a school-internal journal, rather than one intended for broad dissemination. For example, I know of several universities which have "undergraduate research" journals, where undergrads can get experience publishing articles for their undergraduate research projects, without having to compete for space and against the expectations for "standard" journals. -- M.N.M Manzano, you may wish to clarify this point in your question.

Comment: @user2390246: I am not arguing against starting a new journal, but only against starting a new printed journal.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, it is a school based journal, and one based in the Philippines.

Answer (score 3):

Normally journals come in volumes, which may then be divided into issues, so volume 12 might cover all papers for a calendar year but actually be published quarterly as four separate issues: 12(1), 12(2), 12(3), 12(4). Some journals just publish volumes without subdividing, and if you're only printing annually I think it makes sense to do that.